# How can I plot a filled histogram and its density with ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I have this histogram created with ggplot2:

```
x = rnorm(100,0,150)
df <- data.frame(val=c(x))
ggplot(df, aes(val,..density.., fill = ..x..>100)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=bw.SJ(df$val), colour="black") +
  scale_fill_hue(h=c(115,230))
```

I'd like to add the pdf to this histogram, but when the next line is added:

```
geom_density(colour="red", lwd=1) +
```

This returns the error:

```
Error in get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...) : 
  Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you specify `fill = ..x..>100)` inside `geom_histogram` and not for the whole plot. You can't vary the fill colour over a density.

```
ggplot(df, aes(val)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = ..x.. > 100), 
                 binwidth = bw.SJ(df$val), colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_hue(h = c(115, 230)) +
  geom_density(colour = "red", lwd = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work without any arguments in the density call?  If so try

```
geom_density(colour="red", size=1) +
```

instead of

```
geom_density(colour="red", lwd=1) +
```

If that doesn't work, a reproducible example could help.